# Loop through MS Access subform and get column visibility

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I am using one tab control with numerous pages, each stores one subform with a different number of columns. Every subform has to display some basic information, and on demand even more. The `OnLoad` event of each subform defines which column may visible or not.

As part of an export tool, I am trying to build a loop which returns every field **name**, field **caption** and the **visibility** of the column as a boolean.

```
Dim strAns As String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim sfrm As SubForm
Set sfrm = Forms![frm_Main]![frm_Sub]

For Each ctl In sfrm.Controls
    strAns = ctl.Name & "_" & ctl.Caption & "_" & ctl.columnVisible
    Debug.Print strAns
Next ctl
```

Currently it runs only using `ctl.Name`, but I have the feeling this may not be the right syntax for my use-case. It returns every field name AND additionally the name of the textbox beneath it in a new line, so basically this is twice as much information I need.

Does anyone have an idea, how to reach the other two properties?

Comment: have you looked in the project explorer to see the available fields for a control? I would think `.Visible` should work. But the project explorer in the VBE will help you as will the documentation for the control objects of VBA Access - albeit sometimes, MSDN documentation is lacking.

Comment: The `.Visible` returns for each field `True` :(

Comment: Possibly need to reference fields not controls. And use ColumnHidden instead of ColumnVisible. Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa224064(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem, here is a possible workaround! In the meantime I figured out that I doesn't necessarily need the `.Caption` for my specific use-case.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rstQry As DAO.Recordset
Dim fldQry As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qrySource_frmSub")
Set rstQry = qdf.OpenRecordset

Dim dictHidden As New Scripting.Dictionary
For Each fldQry In rstQry.Fields
    dictHidden.Add fldQry.Name, False
Next fldQry
qdf.Close

Dim frm As SubForm
Set frm = Forms![frm_Main]![frm_Sub]

For Each key In dictHidden.Keys
    dictHidden(key) = frm.Controls.item(key).ColumnHidden
Next key
```